# Get Clipped geometry by a given bbox in postgis

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I tried to get the geometry inside a bbox from postgis table, and I follow this [instruction](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html):

And I use the following sql ( the ? will be replaced by the bbox):

`SELECT name, ST_Intersection(geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)) as dest_geom  FROM  table_name where  st_intersects(geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)) = true`

However it seems that the returned features are not as expected, for example some features are not returned.

What's going  on?

And furthermore, as shown in the sql, the `ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)` occurs twice. Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a subquery for `ST_MakeEnvelope()` to avoid doubling. And
adding `= true` is not necessary.

```
 SELECT name, ST_Intersection(table_name.geom, bbox.geom) as dest_geom
 FROM table_name
 JOIN (select ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326) as geom) bbox
 ON st_intersects(table_name.geom, bbox.geom)
```

This is correct and should return the correct geometries. Maybe you use the wrong projection ? Or it is a problem of spheric vs planar bounding box.

[image]
[image]

See https://devjef.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/geometry-vs-geography/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to a certain degree you can simply try to phrase your goal in SQL as a start; if you want to 'SELECT all geometries FROM your table THAT (WHERE) intersects a polygon', do just that:

```
SELECT a.name,
       a.geom AS dest_geom
FROM table_name AS a
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(<xmin>, <ymin>, <xmax>, <ymax>, 4326))
```

EDIT: If that what you need? Or do you want only the exact portions of 'table_name.geom' that intersects with your bbox? Then use:

```
WITH
  bbox AS (
    SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(<minx>, <miny>, <maxx>, <maxy>, 4326) AS geom
  )

SELECT a.name,
       ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS dest_geom
FROM table_name AS a,
     bbox AS b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: pretty much the same as RoVo's answer, though. He was quicker, I didn´t see him answering on my phone...